# Tips in Django Template for send an email with absolute path

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a doubt about the Templates in Django. I create a template for send by html email which extends from the same base.html for all the page in the site (inherited the style, header and footer).

My proble is: All the URL are relative and works fine if I am in my site but the email doesnt see anything because it is outside of the domain.

Should I duplicate the header and footer for the email using absolute path? Should I change all the path in my app from relative to absolute? Is there any filter for change the URL when I render the template?

I hope somebody could give an advice/tips.

Regards,
Cristian

Answer (score 0):

**Sample:**

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def notify_admin(request, topic):
    message = render_to_string('emails/new_speakup_topic.txt', {
            'topic': topic, 'ip_address': get_ip(request)})
    subject = "Topic: {0}".format(topic.title)
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email,
        ['to_email',])
```

create emails folder inside templates folder then put this txt in the emails folder

**sample.txt**

```
{{ topic.title }}
Category: {{ topic.category }}
Author: {{ topic.author.username }}
IP: {{ ip_address }}

{{ topic.description }}

https://site.com/speakup/topic/{{ topic.id }}/
```